# Trying to fill a form returns Cannot query "useraccount": Must be "SellerAccount" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to build a trading market sort of app, and I have models that have foreign keys connected in a multiple level sort of hierarchy. They are as follows:

```py
models.py

class SellerAccount(models.Model):
    # unimportant fields
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
class SellerCardDetail(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    card_name = models.TextField(default="CARDNAME")
    card_quality = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    card_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    card_image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="OPTIONAL, card images do not need to be supplied, but sellers are encouraged to do so.", blank=True)
    card_url = models.URLField()
    card_notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    card_stock = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    seller_details = models.ForeignKey(SellerAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.seller_details.user.username
```

The forms in question are simply formsets with only the required fields added as an argument.

```py
views.py

@login_required(login_url="/account/")
def add_seller_card(request):

    card_form = SellerCardFormSet # imported from forms.py
    user = SellerAccount.objects.get(user=request.user) # imported from models.py

    if request.method == "POST":

        formset = card_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)

        if formset.is_valid():

            formset.save()

            messages.success(request, "Successfully listed a card!")

            return redirect("/")
        else:
            formset = card_form(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, 'account/profile/addcard.html', {"add_card": formset})
    else:
        print(type(user))
        return render(request, 'account/profile/addcard.html')
```

What I thought would happen is that I would get the SellerAccount instance with
`user = SellerAccount.objects.get(user=request.user)` but that has proven to be untrue. I wanted to test what I would get when I let that query through with the simple `print(type(user))`, and it returns `<class 'account.models.SellerAccount'>`. I'm baffled by this, both because my understanding of Django is not good enough, and because this should work in theory and it doesn't.

Since I can't get the user who put in the card as I'm filling the form to do that exact thing, I have become stuck. Any help to undo this mess is appreciated.

## Edit

I have completely looked over the fact that in the line `formset = card_form(instance=request.user)` is supposed to have `instance=user` instead.

However, this brings another question in mind: why is the form invalid, so that it goes directly to that part of the function?

The formset in question for adding a card: `SellerCardFormSet = inlineformset_factory(SellerAccount, SellerCardDetail, fields=('card_name', 'card_quality', 'card_price', 'card_image', 'card_notes', 'card_stock'))` (the SellerCardDetail model has been updated above to detail what this formset represents).

And here is the html for the form itself, using Bootstrap:

```html
<main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
    </br>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">List a card</h1>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" name="card_name" class="form-control" id="floatingInput">
                <label for="floatingInput">Card name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" name="card_quality" class="form-control" id="floatingInput"> 
                <label for="floatingInput">Card quality</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" name="card_price" class="form-control" id="floatingInput">
                <label for="floatingInput">Price</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="file" name="card_image" class="form-control" id="formFile">
                <label for="formFile">Card image</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" name="card_notes" class="form-control" id="floatingInput">
                <label for="floatingPassword">Notes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" name="card_stock" class="form-control" id="floatingInput">
                <label for="floatingInput">Card stock</label>
            </div>

            <fieldset>
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p style="color:red;">{{error}}</p>
                {% endfor %}

                {% if non_field_errors %}
                    <div style="color:red;">
                        <p>{{non_field_errors}}</p>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </fieldset>
            </br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-2" type="submit">List card</button>
        </form>
    </main>
```

Comment: Can you show the error and what line it comes from?

Comment: It seems that I have overlooked one part of the code: the one that goes into the inner else, formset = card_form(instance=request.user) was supposed to have instance=user;